# How to use Coq aac tactics to prove equalities in the goal?

Tags: coq, coq-plugin

I am guessing that Coq `aac_tactics` (8.5p1) should be able to deal with assoc. and commutativity. But I can't figure out how to use it prove simple equalities such as

```
2 + y + 5 = 7 + y
```

For example:

```
Require Import AAC_tactics.AAC.
Require Import AAC_tactics.Instances.
Goal forall y: nat, 2 + y + 5 = 7 + y.
intros ?.  
aac_reflexivity.
```

generates an error:

> Error: Tactic failure: Not an equality modulo A/AC.

Changing the last tactic to `aac_normalise` doesn't solve it either.

How can such goals be proven using AAC?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty scarce, so I can only guess that your example requires some *explicit* rewritings (essentially, you need to show `5 + 2 = 7`).

Notice that the next example works because it doesn't need the fact that `5 + 2 = 7`:

```
Goal forall y : nat, 2 + y + 5 = 5 + y + 2.
  intros ?.
  aac_reflexivity.
Qed.
```

So, if I'd do the original example like this:

```
Goal forall y : nat, 2 + y + 5 = 7 + y.
  intros ?.
  assert (5 + 2 = 7) as H. reflexivity.
  aac_rewrite H.
  aac_reflexivity.
Qed.
```